# Are questions about issues with specific types of equipment off-topic?

Tags: discussion

I understand that the current policy is that recommendations about specific equipment are off-topic.

Are questions about *issues* with specific musical equipment off-topic?

For example:
[How do you sync a Roland Boss RC 300 Loop Station to external rhythm sources?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/17547/how-do-you-sync-a-roland-boss-rc-300-loop-station-to-external-rhythm-sources)

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't call it off-topic, but there is a something we should consider as a site as it is very possible for similar questions to go unanswered for a long period of time. Your question was a very localized question about a very specific model of equipment that no one answered but you much later.

In general on a question like this I would expect the person answering has to have it in order to answer it or the documentation of the equipment be available online for someone to research. It is a possibility that no one on the site has that specific model of equipment and the documentation is unavailable for it. Because of this the question may lie unanswered until we get someone else who has that equipment to join the site and answer the question, or the documentation becomes available which may not happen. Neither of these options may happen and the question may go unanswered.

---

I don't think closing them is a good option, but I also think letting a question sit unanswered forever is any better. We've had questions like this on occasion and we've never really been flooded by them.

I'd say we leave them be, and just be aware that an answer may not come for all questions of this type.

Comment: For this question, I was able to find an approach to the answer online.  But it is an edge case.

Comment: I think I'd agree with Dom here - it's definitely on the edge, but it **is** about making music. So I'd suggest that as long as we can get a helpful and correct answer then let it remain.

Comment: Old unanswered questions with low/no activity, is also not very visible on the site, and so it does not hurt the site that they exist. The problem questions is popular questions that spams the site with non-constructive content (like polls etc.).

Comment: @awe It may not adversely affect the site, but it will affect the user's experience of our site.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a *problem*.

A problem would be:

> I have a TC Polytune, and it works fine on el. guitar and el. bass, but it doesn't work as good on my double bass. Why? What can I do? etc..

These kind of problems aren't off topic.

I don't really know what to say about the question you posted.  Now that I look at it, it doesn't seem way off topic, but it does seem a bit specific. I haven't VTC, and I don't think I will, but let's see what a mod has to say.

Comment: Thanks, @Sheviaskovic.  Changed "problem" to "issue" which I think is more generic.  YMMV.